# Is there any free .NET library for skinning application?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, skinning, skin

I was looking for a .NET library for skinning c# applications, I've found http://www.skincrafter.com

I was wondering if someone knows something like that but free?

Comment: skins are what programmers add to an app when they run out of ideas for real features.

Comment: WPF has extensive features for skinning but somehow I think you mean WinForms.

Comment: @Joel: Agreed - as a general rule, whenever I come across a 'skinned' application it gets unceremoniously dumped.

Comment: The world really needs another skinned app.

Comment: http://www.lextm.com/2008/02/office-2007-style.html

Comment: Actually, what I think the world really needs is more unsolicited opinions from unwarranted-high-ego programmers.

Comment: How about [USkin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/USkin.aspx) ?

Comment: Unsolicited? Asking a question on SO *is* soliciting advice. Part of what's great about SO is that you can get solid advice about what you're asking about, even if the answer isn't necessarily what you're looking for. In this case, Meredith is asking about skinning. Joel volunteered, wisely if perhaps a bit salaciously, that her time would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @Meredith: Commenting on the merits of skinning is about  the best we can do with a question that has [gui], [skin] and [skinning] tags but does not mention what gui. Do you want .css ?

Answer (score -4):

You can always use components from dev express.

Comment: DevExpress components aren't free.